# Address Incrementation of Double pointer and Single pointer

Tags: c, pointers

When a pointer to pointer variable(double pointer) is incremented after initialization and if we access its value gives **RunTime Error**.Whereas in the case of pointer variable, if we access its value after incrementation gives **garbage value**. I am trying hard to understand what may be the reason for this behaviour?

**Using Double pointer:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int  i=10;
    int *j=&i;
    int **k=&j;
    k++;
    printf("%d ",**k);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output: Runtime Error**

**Using Single Pointer:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int  i=10;
    int *j=&i;
    j++;
    printf("%d ",*j);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output: Garbage Value**

Comment: In the second case it's a garbage value, in the first case it's a garbage address. When you dereference *that* it hurts. They are both *undefined behaviour* so anything can happen.

Comment: @WeatherVane The reason for you to say it's *undefined behaviour* because we are accessing uninitialized memory for both the programs.am I right?

Comment: It is undefined behaviour primarily because it is illegal to dereference to an address that is not within the original object, whether or not it was somehow initialised. In the first case, the *result* was to access memory that you are not allowed. In the second case it was garbage.

Answer (score 2):

when you increment the pointer by one it will point to the next memory address, which is in this case 4bytes to the "right" of your original address. There might be a value there, or there might be absolute garbage, or the program you are running is not allowed to read that address. You can't know that beforehand, so you get rather undefined behavior.

Comment: You *do* know that before hand (and as a C programmer you are supposed to) because the C standard says so.